# Getting a PHP error while retrieving data [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little question, I'm working on a small login system for school (it's a project). But, I keep getting this error, which I haven't had before, since the retrieving was working. Does anyone of you maybe know the cause of this problem?

The error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\index.php on line 14

```
<?php
require_once('config.inc.php');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$sesUser."' OR email='".$sesUser."'");
$row = $result->fetch_object();

if(!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
?>
    <li><a href="register.php">Click here to register</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.php">Click here to login</a></li>
<?php
} elseif($_SESSION['logged_in']) {
?>
    <li>Weclome <?php echo $row->username; ?>!</li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">Click here to view your profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.php">Click here to edit your information</a></li>
    <li><a href="forgotpass.php">Click here if you forgot your password</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @JohnConde Sorry, forgot to add that to the post. Here it is: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\index.php on line 14`

Comment: @Peurr I think, that you don't get a row from the database. `var_dump($row)` after $row = $result->fetch_object();. Also print the query, you are running. Try to run in in PHPMyAdmin and let us know, whether you got any result.

Comment: Your SQL is probably failing.  Test the query on the command line.  $result may be 'false' as opposed to an object.

Comment: @user4035 I'm getting this error if I echo the `$result`.. `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\index.php on line 7`

Comment: @user4035 var_dump($row) comes up with `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem happens here

```
$row = $result->fetch_object();
```

That's not returning an object, likely because of a SQL error. So when you run this

```
<li>Weclome <?php echo $row->username; ?>!</li>
```

There's no object to work with. Try this after your query

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$sesUser."' OR email='".$sesUser."'");
echo $conn->error;
```

Comment: Nothing happens if i'm adding the `echo $conn->error`.

Comment: Try `echo $result->error;`

Comment: Gives me this error: `Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$error in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\index.php on line 10` --------- Also, when using `echo $row->error;` I'm getting the same error as in my post above. ( Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\StuffNology-Good\index.php on line 19)

Comment: Ok, the first one is right. And you ran this after your query?

Comment: Yeah, I did run it after the query. @Machavity

Comment: I don't know what I did, but the problem is solved.

Comment: Oh. Duh. had a brain fart there. If you got 0 rows returned then you will also get that error